# Multiple Nested Routes in react-router-dom v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I need multiple nested routes in react-router-dom

***I am using v4 of react-router-dom***

I've got my

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

and I need the components to render like so

```
--- Login
--- Home
    --- Page 1
    --- Page 2
    --- Page 3
--- About
--- etc
```

The Home component contains a Header component that is common to Page1, Page2, and, Page3 components, but is not present in Login and About.

My js code reads like so

```
<Router>
    <div>
        <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
        <Home>
            <Route path='/page1' component={Page1} />
            <Route path='/page2' component={Page2} />
            <Route path='/page3' component={Page3} />
        </Home>
        <Route path='/about' component={About} />
    </div>
</Router>
```

I expect the Login component to show only on /login
When I request for /page1, /page2, /page3, they should contain the Home component and that page's content respectively.

What I get instead is the Login component rendered and below that Page1's component is rendered.

I'm pretty sure that I'm missing something very trivial or making a really silly mistake somewhere, and would appreciate all the help I could get. I've been stuck with this for the last two days.

Comment: you need to add `exact` props on the Route that needs to show on the exact match. <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />

Comment: Tried exact with /login, but my Home component shows up under my Login component.

Comment: @AdityaTalpade check my answare as well

Comment: Hey Aditya, are you able to do this thing?
I also wanted to do the exact same thing.
In my scenario, when the user opens up the website react will redirect it to the login if the user is not logged in. After login, my index page shows up with nav bar and search bar. Now I wanted to show rest of the pages in the body this index page so that all pages will share the same nav bar and search bar.
I would appreciate a lot if you can help me.

Comment: No. I gave it up. Went with react router v3. My workflow was terribly hampered dealing with v4 which wasn't worth the extra effort.

Comment: Once you use React 16, you'll need to make the switch to React Router 4

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use Switch component in router v4

```
<Router>
<Switch>
  <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
  <Route path='/about' component={About} />
  <Home>
    <Route component={({ match }) =>
      <div>
        <Route path='/page1' component={Page1} />
        <Route path='/page2' component={Page2} />
        <Route path='/page3' component={Page3} />
      </div>
    }/>
  </Home>
</Switch>
```

```
export default class Home extends Component {
render() {
    return (
      <div className="Home">
          { this.props.children }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I think this code shows the basic idea of using  component.

Comment: v4 of react-router-dom throws this warning for nested routes
`Warning: You should not use <Route component> and <Route children> in the same route; <Route children> will be ignored
warning` and doesn't render the components under /page1, /page2, etc

Comment: Yes, I saw that there was a problem. I changed the code, try it pls

Comment: @IgorStecyura any possibility you could share the code of the `Home` component?

Comment: @RohanBüchner, Home component looks like this : 

export default class Home extends Component {
render() {
    return (
      <div className="Home">
          { this.props.children }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

I think this code shows the basic idea of using a component

Answer (score 72):

Use the url/path match obtained from props `this.props.match.path` to get the path that is set to a component.

Define your main routes as below

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/" component={DummyIndex} /> {/* Note-1 */}
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route path="/etc" component={Etc} />
  </div>
</Router>
```

Then in `Home` Component, define your routes

```
class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      <Route exact path={this.props.match.path} component={HomeDefault} />
      <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/one`} component={HomePageOne} />
      <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/two`} component={HomePageTwo} />
    </div>
  }
}
```

The defined routes are as below

- /login
- /home
- /home/one
- /home/two
- /about
- /etc

If you want to nest routes further in `HomePageOne` like */home/one/a* and */home/one/b*, you can proceed the same approach.

Note-1: If you don't want further nesting, just set the route with prop `exact`.

**EDIT (May 15, 2017)**

Initially, I've used `props.match.url` and now I changed it to `props.match.path`.

We can use `props.match.path` instead of `props.match.url` in Route's path so that if you use path params in top level routes, you can get it in inner (nested) routes via `props.match.params`.

If you don't you any path params, `props.match.url` is enough

Comment: Im getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined`

Comment: one comment: instead of using <div>, i use <switch> to avoid unnecessary html tags.

Comment: @AshishKamble if you receive `Cannot read property 'path' of undefined`, it means the props `match` is undefined. Make sure that you assign right component to the prop named "component" in Route

Comment: @xiongemi you're right. you can use `<Switch>` but it has a purpose, make sure that you know it.

Comment: To get rid of Cannot read property 'path' of undefined error, you need to pass the props in argument: (props) => props.match.match.url

Answer (score 5):

This week I had the same problem, I think the project is passing for time of confusion because all the documentation, examples and videos are for the previous versions and the docs for the version 4 are confusing
This is how I get the things done, let me know if this help

```or-tag-here
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Root from './Root';
import Home from './Home';
import About from './About';

import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <Root>
                       <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                            <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
                            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                        </Switch>
                    </Root>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This approach will work, but just to clarify for those unfamiliar with React inheritance: that root component will need a return value that contains { props.children }.

Comment: What about `HomepageOne` and `HomepageTwo`

Answer (score 2):

Move all childs routes to parent component and extend route like below. 
`` <Route path={`${match.url}/keyword`} component={Topic}/> `` 
also check [react router training](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic)

Answer (score 1):

Use Like the following:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Link to='/create'> Create </Link>
        <Link to='/ExpenseDashboard'> Expense Dashboard </Link>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/ExpenseDashboard' component={ExpenseDashboard} />
          <Route path='/create' component={AddExpensePage} />
          <Route path='/Edit' component={EditPage} />
          <Route path='/Help' component={HelpPage} />
          <Route component={NoMatch} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

See more @ [Switch on GitHub](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it like this

```
<BrowserRouter>
          <UserAuthProvider>
            <Root>
              <Switch>
                <GuardRoute type="public" exact path="/" component={Login} />
                <GuardRoute type="private" exact path="/home" component={Home} />
                <GuardRoute
                  type="private"
                  exact
                  path="/home/mascotas"
                  component={Mascotas}
                />

              </Switch>
            </Root>
          </UserAuthProvider>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: English is the language used on Stack Overflow. There are some Stack Exchange sites that are in other languages, but this one has a single language.