# Which way to declare nested routes in React-Router-Dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, nested-routes

I'm working with reactJs and trying to create some nested routes.
Below you can see the routing parts of my files :

**main.js :**

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <App />
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('page')
);
```

**App.js :**

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                    <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
                    <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
                    <ProtectedRoute path="/user/profile" component={Profile} />
                    <Route component={NotFound} />
                </Switch>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Don't ask me why, but I want to create the following url's :

- /signup : SignUp form
- /signup/person : SignUp form part 2
- /signup/person/:id : SignUp user id informations

I added this in my `App.js` file and It's works :

```
<Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
<Route exact path="/signup/person" component={SignUpPerson} />
<Route path="/signup/person/:id" component={SignUpId} />
```

But I want to know if it's a good way to create nested routes or it's better to separate the route like this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43846223/4023379

Or maybe an other way ?

Thanks

Comment: It's primarily opinion based what's the best approach. Either one works fine.

Answer (score 0):

use nested routes if **Pages** have common logic/components like Header, Footer.

use separate routes if **Page** doesn't share similar logic. just because of url start with `/singup` not necessary mean you have to nested your components