# Combination of Sidebar and Nested routes using react-router-dom v4 / v5

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I want to implement somewhat a combination of nested routes and sidebar routes in a single route file.
I want the components to render like this.

```
"/" --- Registration page
"/login" ---- Login Page
"/application" --- Application Page
"/dashboard" --- Dashboard page with Sidebar and Application components
"/dashboard/application" --- Dashboard page with Sidebar and Application components
"/dashboard/user" --- Dashboard page with Sidebar and User components
```

I have my routes setup like this

```
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={withAuth(Registration)} />
        <Route path="/login" component={withAuth(Login)} />
        <Route path={'/dashboard'} component={withAuth(Dashboard)}/>        
      </Switch>
```

Inside the dashboard page I have implemented basically the [sidebar example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/sidebar) from react-router-dom website.

It is working fine, however i want to put all the routing in a single file.

Something like this

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/" component={withAuth(Registration)} />
  <Route path="/login" component={withAuth(Login)} />
  <Route path={'/dashboard'} component={withAuth(Dashboard)} children={[Sidebar, Application]}/>
  <Route path="/dashboard/application" component={withAuth(Dashboard)} children={[Sidebar, Application]}/>
  <Route path="/dashboard/user" component={withAuth(Dashboard)} children={[Sidebar, User]}/>
</Switch>
```

The above code is fictional code but it is to give an idea of what I'm trying to achieve. I tried solution from a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984597/multiple-nested-routes-in-react-router-dom-v4/43846223#43846223), but it didn't work for me.

How do i put all the routing in a single file and take care of sidebar routing and nested routing in react-router-dom v4/v5?

I have created a [example code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-nesting-n7cdc), Please try [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-nesting-n7cdc) example.

Comment: what exactly you want ? can you share screenshot for better clarification.

Comment: @VahidAkhtar I have included example code. Read comments in code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-nesting-n7cdc

Comment: I have done something similar to this in a closed-source product. However, I think the answer is that you cannot put all the routing into 1 file. My routing is spread across several files similar to what you have above with a switch in each file. The way I structured it was so that each route's parent component contains the switch and operates as a router for the sub-menu for that section of the web app.

Answer (score 1):

While I think having all your routes in one file has become anti-pattern, I think you can achieve something close enough to what you're looking for - specifically, getting all the routes to reside in the same file.

The main trick is using the switch like a [normal switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). The last case in the `Switch` becomes the default case (or route).

You also need to use [exact](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#exact-bool) because without it, it will match the URL `/` every time. The same is true of the second `Switch` inside `InternalRoutes`. If you don't include `exact`, it will match `/dashboard` every time and never get to `/dashboard/application` or `dashboard/user`. You'll still need the `Routes` component to be wrapped in a `BrowserRouter` component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const Routes = props => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={withAuth(Registration)} />
      <Route exact path="/login" component={withAuth(Login)} />
      <Route component={withAuth(InternalRoutes)} />
    </Switch>
  );
};

const InternalRoutes = props => {
  return (
    <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={withAuth(Dashboard)} children={[Sidebar, Application]}/>
    <Route exact path="/dashboard/application" component={withAuth(Dashboard)} children={[Sidebar, Application]}/>
    <Route exact path="/dashboard/user" component={withAuth(Dashboard)} children={[Sidebar, User]}/>
    <Route component={NotFoundComponent} />
  );
};

const NotFoundComponent = props => {
  return <div>URL Not Found</div>;
};

export default Routes;
```