# How can I remove Footer Component only in specific page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class

(I'm using React - **Class Component**)

I'm looking for how to remove Footer component only in specific page, but i have no idea. Actually I don't have no idea about what keyword to search.

Below code is my Router.js

```
class Routes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Main}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/review" component={ReviewPage}></Route>
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default Routes;
```

I put Footer and Navbar Component in router like that because those are always exists in every page. But unfortunately I just found that in ReviewPage, there is NO FOOTER....

How can i remove Footer only in ReviewPage?
Please give me hint !

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65655479/seperate-route-from-rest-of-layout-react/65655723#65655723

Comment: include the ```<Footer />``` just inside the ```Main``` component and not in the ```Routes``` component ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `window.location.pathname`.It returns the current url path name. And then you can set a condition as below:

```
{window.location.pathname !== '/review' && <Footer />}
```

### Solution

```
class Routes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Main}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/review" component={ReviewPage}></Route>
        </Switch>
        {window.location.pathname !== '/review' && <Footer /> }
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default Routes;
```

Answer (score 0):

{Location.pathname === '/photographer/:id' && }

and you can see new version React-router

Now use Location != location and it works

```
    <>
        <Header />
        <main>
            <Container>
            
                <Routes>
                    <Route path='/' element={<HomeScreen />}></Route>
                    <Route
                        path='/photographer/:id'
                        element={<PhotographersScreen/>}
                        ></Route>
                </Routes>
                
            </Container>
        </main>
        {Location.pathname === '/photographer/:id' && <Footer />}
    </>
```